# Call class variable without using class name

Tags: python, class

Is there a way to call a class variable from within a method, without using the class name?

So instead of:

```
class ClassTest:
    var1 = 5
    def __init__(self, var2):
        self.var2 = var2 
        print(ClassTest.var1*self.var2)
```

How could I call the class name avoiding having to specify the class name `ClassTest`?

Comment: If you use function 'dir' like dir(instance), you can see all available methods and functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `self.__class__` or `type(self)` to refer the class object from instance.

**Edit:**

The other answers mentioned to use `self.var1` to access class-level name `var1`, but this would get the instance's attribute `var1` if the instance has one. So you'll need to make sure the instance does not have such an attribute.

In any way, it is safer to use `self.__class__.var1` or `type(self).var1`, and also gives an indication to the next reader that the attribute is a class attribute.